# Integration by parts in higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I would like to know if it is possible to write
$$
\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n
$$
in terms of
$$
\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}\Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n
$$
I was thinking about some kind of integration by parts, although I'm not sure if it can be done, and in the affermative case I'm note sure how to do it. I have read lots of related post on MSE but unfortunately I don't fully understand the concept.. at least I couldn't apply it in my case. In general I read that for all pair of functions $u$,$v$ such that $u,v\in C^1$ we have that:
$$
\int_{\Omega}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} d\Omega = \int_{\partial\Omega}uv\nu_i d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} d\Omega
$$
where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set (such as in my case $(0,2\pi)^n$). My idea was to define the function $v$ as the following function:
$$
v(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n) = \Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k}
$$
and $u$ such that:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta_i} = \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)
$$
So I would have something like:
$$
\int_{\Omega}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} d\Omega = \int_{[0,2\pi]^n}\Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n
$$
which is the integral I would like to reduce.

Unfortunately I don't know if this process would be correct.

**Progress**

Maybe using $i=3$ as the index of the derivative we found something like:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta_3} = \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) \implies u(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n) = \theta_3\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)
$$

and this also implies that:

$$
\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n =
$$
$$
= \int_{\partial[0,2\pi]^n} \theta_3\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\Bigl(\sum_{i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k}\nu_3 d\Gamma.
$$
In fact the integral
$$
\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta_i} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n
$$
seems to vanish everytime. Furthermore the integral over the boundary can be written as (since $\nu_3$ is the third component of the normal vector of the boundary of the hypercube):
$$
\int_{[0,2\pi]^{n-1}}2\pi\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\Bigl(\sum_{i\not =3}^{n}\cos(\theta_i)+\sum_{i,j\not = 3, i<j}^{n}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k}d\theta_1 d\theta_2 d\theta_4 \dots d\theta_n
$$
In fact the previous integral only considered two faces of the hypercube, the first with $\theta_3 = 0$ and the other one with $\theta_3 = 2\pi$. For $\theta_3 = 0$ the integral trivially vanishes and for $\theta_3 = 2\pi$ we have the above. We can also write the previous integral as:
$$
2\pi\int_{[0,2\pi]^{n-1}}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\cos(\theta_i)+\sum_{i<j}^{n-1}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Bigr)^{k}d\theta_1 \dots d\theta_{n-1}
$$
using a trivial change of variables.

Could we do more progress?

**Background of the question**

This question is basically based on a try to prove an asymptotic formula for the second integral using induction, more details in the following post:
[Asymptotic formula for a multidimensional definite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737539/asymptotic-formula-for-a-multidimensional-definite-integral)

Comment: I am not sure how Integration by parts should be applied here. Can you show your ideas in the one or two dimensional case?

Comment: I add some informations regarding my main idea, although I don't know if it is possible.. probably I just misundestand the concept of this generalization of integration by parts

Comment: The multidimensional counterpart of integration by parts that I have most commonly seen basically ["trades two gradients for a Laplacian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_first_identity).  Not sure if that can be applied here though.

Comment: I have used this kind of integration by parts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263867/find-a-rigorous-reference-that-prove-the-following-integration-by-parts-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1